# How to programmatically rename column names in AWS Glue Catalog

Tags: aws-glue

I have populated the Glue Catalog for 25 tables using crawler. Now the table names all have generic columnn name. Is there any better way to programmatically rename the columns rather than doing it manually one by one? I also dont want to write the same data again with different column name. I came across the RenameField Class but not sure whether it will just rename the catalog or write the whole data again?

Comment: you can use: `newDyF = oldDyF.rename_field("`this.old.name`", "thisNewName")`. one of the glue functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-drop_fields

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a Glue ETL Job the columns can be renamed with the [ApplyMapping class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ApplyMapping.html):

```
# Glue ETL script for python
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(
frame = datasource0, 
mappings = [
    ("column_1", "string", "column_1", "string"),
    ("column_2", "string", "column_2", "string"),
    ("partition_0", "string", "year", "string"), 
    ("partition_1", "string", "month", "string"), 
    ("partition_2", "string", "day", "string"), 
    ("partition_3", "string", "hour", "string")
    ], 
    transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

In the above example partitions 0-3 are renamed to year, month, hour day.

Answer (score 1):

## 1.

You can use boto3 sdk to create tables instead of running crawler.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_table
glue.create_table(DatabaseName=, TableInput=)
The TableInput parameter takes a json format where you can define the table column name.

'Columns': [
                {
                    'Name': 'string',
                    'Type': 'string',
                    'Comment': 'string'
                },
            ],

You can construct the 'Columns' element writing a python code to read the source table (s3 file or MySQL table or which ever is your source definition)
Once you have the json you can write a python script to execute the create_table.

## 2. Another way if you have already created the table definition using crawler is to get the definition of table.

a)  Rename the columns. 
b) Do #1. 
c) Drop table.

```
response = client.delete_table(
CatalogId='string',
DatabaseName='string',
Name='string'
                            )
```

d) Create table

## 3. You can do it in your Glue code without changing table definition.

Rename columns

```
for c in cust_addressDF.columns:
        cust_addressDF = cust_addressDF.withColumnRenamed(c , "cust_"+c)
```

Here cust_addressDF is spark DataFrame created from Glue DynamicFrame. This will append columns with "cust_" at runtime.

I am doing #1 and #3 in my process.